# unexpected results which is empty array

Tags: javascript

when I run code, I see empty array, but I aim to have an array with some vowels.

```js
let input = 'zai';
const vowels = ['a', 'u', 'o', 'e', 'i'];
let resultArray = [];

for (let inputindex = 0; inputindex < input.inputindex; inputindex++) {
  for (let vowel = 0; vowel > vowels.length; vowel++) {
    if (input[inputindex] === vowels[vowel]) {
      resultArray.push(input[inputindex])
    }
  }
}

console.log(resultArray)
```

Comment: Condition `vowel > vowels.length` is backwards so inner loop never runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done a mistake by writing `input.inputindex` instead of `input.length`. Plus, you have wrote `vowel > vowel.length` instead of `vowel < vowels.length`. That's why your loop didn't run at least a single loop and ended up with an empty array. Correct the code as below and try again...

```
let input = 'zai';
const vowels = ['a', 'u', 'o', 'e', 'i'];
let resultArray = [];

for (let inputindex = 0; inputindex < input.length; inputindex++) {
  for (let vowel = 0; vowel < vowels.length; vowel++) {
    if (input[inputindex] === vowels[vowel]) {
      resultArray.push(input[inputindex])
    }
  }
}

console.log(resultArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

input string but you need array, i use split.
and some mistakes in loops

```
let input = 'zai';
let input2 = input.split('')
const vowels = ['a', 'u', 'o', 'e', 'i'];
let resultArray = [];

 for(let inputindex = 0; inputindex < input2.length; inputindex++){
   for(let vowel = 0; vowel < vowels.length; vowel++){
     if(input2[inputindex] === vowels[vowel]){
       resultArray.push(input2[inputindex])
     }
   }
 }

display.log(resultArray)
```

Without array

```
let input = 'zai';
const vowels = ['a', 'u', 'o', 'e', 'i'];
let resultArray = [];

 for(let inputindex = 0; inputindex < input2.length; inputindex++){
   for(let vowel = 0; vowel < vowels.length; vowel++){
     if(input.slice(inputindex, inputindex+1) === vowels[vowel]){
       resultArray.push(input.slice(inputindex, inputindex+1))
     }
   }
 }

display.log(resultArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

looping through the inputs and comparing them with each value in vowels using the `.some` method as so:

```js
let input = 'zai';
let vowels = ['a', 'u', 'o', 'e', 'i'];
let resultArray = [];

for (let inputindex = 0; inputindex < input.length; inputindex++) {
    if (vowels.some(v => v === input[inputindex])) {
      resultArray.push(input[inputindex])
  }
}

console.log(resultArray)
```